# Having difficulty in selecting commit by message instead of hash for --fixup

Tags: git

I was looking for a way to select commits using the commit message instead of the relation from HEAD or the commit hash and found that it was possible, but I cannot get it to work.

I do have a previous commit, which has a commit message that starts with "Enable git rebase --autosquash" (as an example).

```
$ git add -u
$ git commit --fixup=amend:/'Enable git rebase --autosquash' -m "New message example"
fatal: could not lookup commit /Enable git rebase --autosquash
```

As I said, there is a commit which has a message which starts with that string. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have quite the right syntax.

Recall that:

1. The syntax of the `--fixup` option is `--fixup=[(amend|reword):]<commit>`
2. The syntax for specifying a commit by string is `:/<string>`.

If you replace `<commit>` in the first rule with the syntax from the second rule, you get:

```
git commit --fixup=amend::/'Enable git rebase --autosquash'
```

Note the two colons.